# .NET WebService : Function called by POST or GET

Tags: .net, web-services, post, get

I have a WEBSERVICE using a function called today by POST, which work well. This function does not not any parameters and return a decimal.

However, I need to POST parameters so the server can compute and return also a value.

This 'POST' function has exactly the SAME name as function A (it works usually in the system).

I have tried to tell the server to distinguish between POST and GET, but unfortunately, it only takes the POST and reject the GET (for info, I have other GET functions who are working well).

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Function test() As Decimal
xxx
End Function

<WebMethod()>
Public Function fees(ByVal price As Decimal) As Decimal
xxxx
End Function
```

Any idea how to have GET and POST using the same reference ?

Thanks, Fred

Comment: I usually just name the methods in the controller Post and Get respectively, in addition to tagging them with [HttpPost] and/or [HttpGet] attributes. Not sure if that applies to you though, but I've never had an issue with it. Is this ASP.Net MVC or something else?

Comment: Well, this is what we do now =-) but for this entry, I have no choice, we did that long time ago. we are using ASP.NET WebForm > Webservice and calls are made using AJAX request.